# Maximizing $g(x)$ and monotone transformation $f(g(x)$ is the same?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have encountered that in some cases maximization of a function had been substituted with a maximization of its monotone transformation.

For example, 
finding the min or max of $f(x,y) = ((x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2)^{1/2}$ is the same as finding the min / max of $(x^2 + y^2)$  and then take the square root of the answer. So, my questions are:

1) Is it true for any monotone transformation $g$?

2) Is the same principle allow us to maximize /minimize $\log g(x)$ instead of $g(x)$ itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is true and, if the optimal is not on the boundary, it doesn't need to be monotonic.f objective function is $f(x)$ and a transformation is made to the variable/s $x=g(y)$.

$$\frac {df(g(y))}{dy}=f^{'}(x)g^{'}(y)$$ $$\frac {d^2f(g(y))}{dy^2}=f^{''}(x)(g^{'})^2+f^{'}g^{''}(y)$$ at the optimal point $x_0$ $$f^{'}(x_0)=0$$ therefore,

$$\frac {d^2f(g(y))}{dy^2}=f^{''}(x)(g^{'})^2$$
So if it the minimum/maximum of f, it should be min/max of $f(g(y))$. At this time, both functions are assumed to be derivative.